# CreateFile w/ CREATE_NEW Equivalent in iOS?

Tags: ios, multithreading, file

Is there a way to open a file for write only successfully when the file does not exist before opening?

I am doing some threaded work where some files have to be created at some point. Random filename may help, but I want to make sure there is no collision

Thanks in advance

Comment: The described functionality in the Windows platform is by the CreateFile function with the CREATE_NEW flag. Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have not much idea of what you are trying to accomplish but you can do the following to check for the existence of a file :-

```
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *yourFile = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFilewithExtension"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:yourFile];
```

"fileExists" will return yes if file exists else no.

Comment: the fileExistsAtPath check will only guarantee the existence at one point during the execution of the function. However, what I want to achieve is to open a file for write, if it doesn't exist, then it will open (and the file is created then), otherwise, it will fail. So even when two threads try the same filename, only one will succeed at getting a file handle for write

Answer (score 0):

Append "x" in the mode string

> Finally, as an extension to the standards (and thus may not be
>   portable), mode string may end with the letter `x'', which insists on
>   creating a new file when used with`w'' or ``a''.  If path exists,
>   then an error is returned (this is the equivalent of specifying O_EXCL
>   with open(2)).

http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fopen.3.html